# Calculating distance between two points on line string

Tags: geometry, algorithm, linestring

I have a line string and two points with me. I need to understand how to calculate the distance between two points along the provided line string. Also, note that in some cases, the provided points can be the same as the points in the line strings.

Case 1:

```
point_1 = [145.01335373083108, -37.83531345902471]
point_2 = [145.0133087,-37.8355784]
line_string = [[145.0123086, -37.8323874], [145.0124038, -37.8323978], [145.0127101, -37.8324314], [145.0130083, -37.8324631], [145.0131113, -37.8325173], [145.0131586, -37.8325914], [145.0135326, -37.8332436], [145.0136158, -37.833392], [145.0136377, -37.8334482], [145.0136437, -37.8335063], [145.0136287, -37.833663], [145.0135595, -37.8340508], [145.013449, -37.8346943], [145.0134461, -37.8347113], [145.0134418, -37.8347953], [145.0133087, -37.8355784], [145.0132317, -37.8360771], [145.0132176, -37.8361681]]
```

Case 2:

```
point_1 = [145.0135595,-37.8340508]
point_2 = [145.0133087,-37.8355784]
line_string = [[145.0123086, -37.8323874], [145.0124038, -37.8323978], [145.0127101, -37.8324314], [145.0130083, -37.8324631], [145.0131113, -37.8325173], [145.0131586, -37.8325914], [145.0135326, -37.8332436], [145.0136158, -37.833392], [145.0136377, -37.8334482], [145.0136437, -37.8335063], [145.0136287, -37.833663], [145.0135595, -37.8340508], [145.013449, -37.8346943], [145.0134461, -37.8347113], [145.0134418, -37.8347953], [145.0133087, -37.8355784], [145.0132317, -37.8360771], [145.0132176, -37.8361681]]
```

[image]

Comment: You had tags for software not mentioned in your question. You have provided no code so I assume you are seeking an algorithm. For that I suspect Maths would be the site to research at.

Comment: Are the two points always on the line and how do you check on that? Are you looking for some kind of pseudo-code?

Comment: Which programming language you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS expressions, there is the function [`line_locate_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#line-locate-point) that gives you the point's distance from the start-point of the line, along the linestring. Points are snapped to the line. Use the difference of these two values to get the distance of the points from each other along the line.

The whole expression to find the distance along the closes line on layer `line` form the current point to the next point (point with next $id value) is:

```
line_locate_point (
    overlay_nearest ('line',$geometry)[0],  
    geometry (
        get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1)  
    )
)-
line_locate_point (
    overlay_nearest ('line',$geometry)[0], 
    $geometry  
)
```